# ZipArchive gives blank screen PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, zip

I enabled php_zip.dll in php.ini and it shows up in phpinfo, so ZipArchive is enabled. Next, here is the code I am using:

```
$zipname='exports.zip';
$zip=new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

When my code reaches this point, the screen goes blank. There are no errors in my error log. My HTML is supposed to show, but it does not. All other unessential PHP is commented out. I am using PHP 5.2.4 on a Wordpress 3.9.2 site.

Comment: Well are you generating any output to appear on a screen?

Comment: @MarkBaker, I changed the question a little

Comment: Are you getting any return from the call to `$zip->open()`? You can test it with `$result = $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE); var_dump($result);die();`

Comment: @MarkBaker I narrowed it down; it barfs on the second line, not the first or third

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for those finding this in search engines. Instead of using php's ZipArchive, I used a command line with WinZip. It looked like this:

```
$cmd='"C:\Winzip-Directory\winzip32.exe" -a "C:/zip-directory/exports.zip" "C:/zip-directory"';
exec($cmd);
```

I still don't know what caused the problem with PHP's ZipArchive, though.